# Websites loading sluggishly - Wireshark shows data transfer is quick

Tags: networking, google-chrome, browser, wireshark

I have a Windows 10 x64 PC with plenty of resources and a fast network connection. The last week or so loading websites have been pretty sluggish. I use Chrome (kept up to date) as my primary browser, but I have tested and the same issue happens to Internet Explorer and Egde as well (I practically never use these). It happens to both sites that are in the cache and ones that are not. Clearing cache, cookies etc. does not make a difference - yes, I tried.

For every single site I try, it seems like the TTFB (Time To First Byte) value is very high - usually it hovers pretty close to 3.30 seconds, I have seen a times where I got higher values (4.5 seconds for instance), and a VERY few instances where the TTFB has been as low as 1.28 seconds. Usually, loading most of these sites happened at the blink of an eye (fiber connection). I have a 10ms average ping to the site I use the most, which now averages at a TTFB of 3.30 seconds (surprisingly little variation in the numbers after hundereds of tests).

Now, here is the kicker: If I run Chrome (or one of the other browsers), the devtools and Wireshark (latest) side by side, I see that the actual data transfer is fairly quick - typically 0.2 seconds for the site I use most often - but that the outgoing http request does not happen until the end of the TTFB wait. That is, browser thinks it has made the request, sits down to wait for the first byte, 3.1 seconds pass, THEN the actual http GET request is made, and data is returned 0.2 seconds after that. This is extremely consistent and entirely reproducible.

Trough process of elimination I have concluded that this is related to the machine I am on. Another PC (also Win 10, but weaker specs) in the same network accessing the same site does not have the same issue.

I have disabled all Chrome extensions, to no effect.

I have Bitdefender Total Security 2017 build 21.0.24.54 installed. However, it has been here way longer than the problem. I'm not ruling it out, but the problem did not start with the installation of Bitdefender. Of course, there could have been a software or definition update, so I can't say for sure it isn't related.

There is no proxy configured. There is no VPN enabled. And as mentioned, it happens on sites which should be in the cache as well as sites I have never visited before on this machine (I've tested extensively).

So, my wizards.. How do I figure out why the wait happens before the request is actually transmitted across the network?

Let me know what you need to know about the setup or of any tests you want run, and I shall provide. I am most interested in figuring this out because it is frankly killing the usefulness of the browser on the machine.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens in your wireshark capture between the click the the first byte? Are there DNS lookups, ARP or any other activity? My first suspicion with that kind of delay is a name resolution issue (i.e. first and/or second attempt timeout, then success), possibly due to misconfigured DNS settings, bad caching, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I should have specified - this happens regardless of the website being in the DNS cache or not. Also, DNS lookups are very quick.

Comment: As for the different browsers - as mentioned, I use Chrome usually, but I have tested IE and Edge as well. Will download Firefox and see if that is affected.

Comment: Can you post an anonymized screenshot of a capture that starts at the same time as the click?

Comment: Yeah, we need a packet trace to look at things like DNS lookups, TCP handshake, and TLS handshake. Also if any Happy Eyeballs IPv6 vs IPv4 racing is going on, and perhaps any HTTP[/2] vs QUIC (TCP vs UDP) racing, or anything like that.

Comment: I will produce a packet trace as soon as I am near the computer tomorrow morning (CET)!